# How do you make an inline SVG scale full-screen to background-size and still be able to be animated?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, frontend

It is possible to get an SVG or image to scale nicely with background css such as:

```
.svg_background {
    background: url("example.svg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
}
```

However, I don't think you can do CSS animations like this. I tried a partial workaround where I base64 encoded the SVG into the URL reference and was able to include inline CSS styling that way, but the trouble is that inline CSS styling doesn't seem to have a way to add the keyframes necessary for animation.

So, the simplest solution would be to keep the SVG completely inline and figure out a way to resize it without background related CSS.

That way, CSS animations can be done of the SVG.

Any ideas how to resize an inline SVG or image to adjust to fullscreen?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably the same way you would fullscreen any image...use a full page div (probably positioned) to hold the SVG. It should scale automagically.

Comment: Don't think the behavior is possible with CSS, unless there's a way to have it automatically crop and resize the way it can with background CSS? I found something related you said a few months ago "As far as I know you can't use animated SVG as actual images (yet). Background-image is a currently a non-animatable property so it wouldn't work. Hope I'm wrong..this would be interesting." at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633655/css-background-image-svg-animated-does-not-working but I'm trying to make a workaround.

Comment: I'm attempting the other approach now of maintaining the background image but trying to get CSS styling and specifically @keyframes to work for animation.

Comment: Instead of CSS used <animate> tags in the SVG file and made equivalent functionality by referencing docs: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#AnimateElement  It works perfectly now in Chrome and Safari but unfortunately not Firefox.

Comment: I'm not sugegsting using it as a background image. Put the SVG in a div and set that as fixed position full screen...should work...shouldn't it?

Comment: Ah, sorry the wording in my question is ambiguous, but the `height:100vh; width: 100vw;` in the CSS above when used on a background image makes the image go to full-screen, but then also allows for content to be put below it so that you can scroll past the image. I believe what you're suggesting makes the image hang permanently on the screen. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for helping.